# Creating PS functions that are to be run locally and remotely

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

First time poster and Powershell novice here,

I am wondering what the most elegant way of writing a Powershell function that can be both run locally and remotely.

What I have come up with is something along the lines of:

```
function helperFunction {do something}

function myFunction
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $True)]
        [string[]]$ComputerName
    )

    # If to be run on remote computer
    if ($ComputerName)
    {
       ForEach ($computer in $ComputerName)
       {
           # Establish PSSession:
           $session = New-PSSession

           # Do something:
           Invoke-Command -Session $session -command ${Function:helperFunction}
            
           Remove-PSSession $session
       }
    }
    else
    {
        # Run helper function:
        helperFunction
    }

}
```

This seems to be the most simple way I can think of. I would just like to know if there's any kind of Powershell trickery that I'm missing here.

Thanks and best wishes,
James

Comment: This is going to depend on _what_ you're trying to do; I've written probably about a hundred different advanced functions/script cmdlets, many of which can be run remotely or which can run on the local computer and act on a remote computer. The techniques you use are going to depend on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I have just started putting together my first module and will no doubt want to do many different things such as configure workstations, GPO's and collect information. It's been great fun so far! No doubt the nuances of advanced function writing will reveal themselves in due course.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Jeff Zeitlin, it really depends on what you want to do. There are some few tips and tricks I can recommend though.

One being the `Try{}Catch{}` block. It really is a more formal way of dealing with unwanted errors. Heres a quick example:

```
Function Do-Stuff{
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,
               ValueFromPipeLine=$True,
               ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
               [Alias("CN","Name")]
               [ValidateLenght(0,15)]
               [String[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
               )
Process{
    try{
        foreach($Computer in $ComputerName){
            
            $PSSession  = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction Stop
            $CIMSession = New-CimSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -ErrorAction Stop
            
            }
        } Catch [System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException] {
            "Unable to connect to PC: $Computer `n$($Error[0].Exception.Message.Split('.')[2].Trim())!"

        } Catch [Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimException] {
            "Unable to establish CIM Session on PC: $Computer `n$($Error[0].Exception.Message.Split('.')[2].Trim())!"

        } Finally {
            if($PSSession) { Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession }
            if($CIMSession) { Get-CimSession | Remove-CimSession }
        }
    }
}
```

A lot of people tend to use an echo request (*ping*) to see if a machine is online, and if it is, run something against it. The issue with that is, even though its gotten a echo reply, it doesnt necessarily mean you can run commands against it. So if you try to establish a session, its pretty much a guaranteed the following cmdlets run against it will work.

In the `Finally` block we clear the sessions we opened for proper cleanup but, this can be done just as easily using an `end{}` block too.

There are a few parameter attributes you can add as well that can be helpful in the long run such as `ValidateLength` for the computer name. In my environment, every computer name is 15 characters long and I use that to throw an error if they type in an extra char.